# Unable to recognize Dictionary object through Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I am playing with Reflections and stopped with the next problem.

I can't recognize that the object is of the Dictionary<,> Type.

I receive PropertyInfo from Top object, and this property is of Dictionary<,> class for sure.

Then I do the next:

```
 if (pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType && pi.PropertyType == typeof(IDictionary<,>))
```

or

```
 if (pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType && pi.PropertyType == typeof(KeyValuePair<,>))
```

and in both cases the second comparision's without success.

Does anyone know another way to 100% recognize a Dictionary Type object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type in the `PropertyType` is a closed generic type (`Dictionary<string, int>` for example) where the type parameters are known. You want to check if the type is any `Dictionary<,>` (called an open generic type).

You should do:

```
pi.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Dictionary<,>)
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked.